# How to tell Renovate to use AWS-Codeartifact URLs in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, aws-codeartifact, renovate

I'm using Renovate in self hosted Gitlab to update my AWS-CDK projects. This works so far, but I figured that Renovate is not using AWS-Codeartifact URLs for package-log.json. Instead there are URLs to registry.npmjs.org

This is my renovate.json inside of a CDK project

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "prHourlyLimit": 0,
  "rangeStrategy":"update-lockfile"
}
```

This is an example snippet of package-lock.json currently generated by Renovate

```
"constructs": {
  "integrity": "sha512-MIwjmrXZpM9RtwyrSD4HotDIQl8HTdIefQhU+MU1asvtSyVN3kK8kjeUOWMFb+fdyT4RX3QvvcaaPBluLEX1SA=="
  "version": "10.2.69",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/constructs/-/constructs-10.2.69.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-0AiM/uQe5Uk6JVe/62oolmSN2MjbFQkOlYrM3fFGZLKuT+g7xlAI10EebFhyCcZwI2JAcWuWCmmCAyCothxjuw=="
},
```

But I like it to look like this

```
"constructs": {
  "integrity": "sha512-MIwjmrXZpM9RtwyrSD4HotDIQl8HTdIefQhU+MU1asvtSyVN3kK8kjeUOWMFb+fdyT4RX3QvvcaaPBluLEX1SA=="
  "version": "10.2.69",
  "resolved": "https://domain-012345678901.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com:443/npm/repo/constructs/-/
  "integrity": "sha512-0AiM/uQe5Uk6JVe/62oolmSN2MjbFQkOlYrM3fFGZLKuT+g7xlAI10EebFhyCcZwI2JAcWuWCmmCAyCothxjuw=="
},
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried to extend renovate.json by [defaultRegistryUrls](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#defaultregistryurls) property without success

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "defaultRegistryUrls": ["https://domain-012345678901.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com:443/npm/repo"],
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "prHourlyLimit": 0,
  "rangeStrategy":"update-lockfile"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `npmrc` attribute in your Renovate configuration with the same content as you'd have in your `.npmrc` file on your laptop or CI:

```json
{
  "npmrc": "registry=..."
}
```

*If I remember well, this should be sufficient. If not, you might need to add a `packageRule` as well.*